# I am getting an error in xcode (no available overloads)

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var leftimageview: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var rightimageview: UIImageView!

   @IBOutlet weak var leftscorelabel: UIStackView!
   @IBOutlet weak var rightscorelabel: UIStackView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarnng() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   @IBAction func resetbutton(_sender: Any) {
      print("resetgame")
      leftimageview.image = UIImage()
   }
}
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to change the picture displayed when the button in my project is pressed.

Comment: Please copy your code to question and format it, instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: use `leftimageview.image = UIImage(named: "rosemary")`

Comment: leftimageview.image = UIImage(name : "rosemary") and I am still getting the error

Comment: Thank you so much for the fix :D !

Comment: @ShamasS ; the o.p. could ***not*** post a screenshot as they need to earn enough reputation (10 or 20?) to get that priviledge.  They'll get the hang of it.  And welcome to StackOverflow, Julius!

Comment: @MichaelDautermann My point is that OP should not post screenshot at all. Instead OP should copy/paste their code to question. So that it  can be indexed/searched.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UIImage` like this in one of 2 ways:

- Using the `UIImage(named:)` constructor

  `leftimageview.image = UIImage(named: "rosemary")`
- The more Swifty way, using an image literal

  `leftimageview.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rosemary")`

You can use a Swift Image Literal in Xcode by starting to type `Image Literal` and use the autocomplete and select your image

Answer (score 0):

If you are using image literals, you do not need to use the `UIImage` constructor, just do `leftimageview.image = rosemary` where rosemary is the image literal in your screenshot (shown with the image preview, in reality, it is `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "rosemary")`)